# Update String using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

With below code I'm attempting add a style to a string using regex, but instead of
'updated' being set to `<'span style='color:blue' >test</span> text'` 
its being set as `'test text'`. Am I misusing regex ?

src :

```
var text = 'test text';
var stringToStyle = 'test';                   
var update = "<span style='color:blue' >" + stringToStyle + "</span>";
var updated = text.replace('/'+stringToStyle+'/gi' , update);

console.log(update);
console.log(updated);
```

plunkr : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6uO3M8kATQLXvWWVx1Vw?p=preview

Comment: that isn't very safe.

Comment: Looks like you come from PHP. Try `var updated = text.replace(RegExp(stringToStyle, "gi") , update);`

Comment: Why did you choose to accept an "unsafe" solution? Just curious.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know 'stringToStyle' will not contain regex characters so I accepted the simpler solution. I do appreciate your answer and did upvote, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a string, not a regex, into `.replace`. Note that this isn't very safe in the case `stringToStyle` has regex control chars.

```
var regexp = new RegExp(stringToStyle, 'gi');
var updated = text.replace(regexp, update);
```

or you could just pass `stringToStyle` directly, which would be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Note you can't concatenate variables with regex delimiters like you can in PHP.
You need to use a [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor notation to build your dynamic pattern using variables.
You can safely use

```
var updated = text.replace(RegExp(stringToStyle.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"), "gi") , update);
```

The `.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")` comes from this [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). This "trick" will escape all the special metacharacters that must be escaped for a regex pattern.

If you use

```
var updated = text.replace(stringToStyle, update);
```

It will perform one single replacement. Perhaps, it is all you need.